# how to do for o foreach cycle jquery

Tags: jquery, css, foreach

how to do cycle and that the same statement is not repeated, each ítem displays different content
thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/acuario1220/jwy65yp3/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 var sub_menu_timer;


$('.nav-item1, .containerMenu1').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('.containerMenu1').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('.containerMenu1').hide();
    }
});

$('.nav-item2, .containerMenu2').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('.containerMenu2').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('.containerMenu2').hide();
    }
});

$('.nav-item3, .containerMenu3').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('.containerMenu3').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('.containerMenu3').hide();
    }
});


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use different classes for each element. Give them the same class so you can bind them all at once. Use a `data-XXX` attribute to relate the menu items to the containers that should be shown.

HTML:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="containerMenu containerMenu1">1</div>
    <div class="containerMenu containerMenu2">1</div>
    <div class="containerMenu containerMenu2">1</div>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="nav-item" data-container="containerMenu1">ITEM 1</div>
        <div class="nav-item" data-container="containerMenu2">ITEM 2</div>
        <div class="nav-item" data-container="containerMenu3">ITEM 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".nav-item").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $('.' + $(this).data('container')).show();
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $('.' + $(this).data('container')).hide();
        }
    });

    $(".containerMenu").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).show();
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/jwy65yp3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I can advise you to use partial selector for such cases like

```
$('div[class*="nav-item"], div[class*="containerMenu"]').on('mouseenter',function(){
    var classToShow = '.containerMenu' + $(this).attr('class').match(/\d+/);
    $(classToShow).toggle();
});
```

It will make your code muuch shorter, even comparing to `.each` method.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwy65yp3/3/)

Answer (score 0):

*Guessing you respect some kind of order*

You can use in/out hover method handler and `toggle()` method. BTW, use common class and index that way:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    $('.nav-item').hover(function(){
        $(".containerMenu").eq($(this).index()).toggle();
    });
});
```

With HTML:

```
 <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="containerMenu containerMenu1">1</div>
        <div class="containerMenu containerMenu2">2</div>
        <div class="containerMenu containerMenu3">3</div>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="nav-item">ITEM 1</div>
            <div class="nav-item">ITEM 2</div>
            <div class="nav-item">ITEM 3</div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwy65yp3/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding event to the different classes, you could make it as generic which helps for future modification and re usability

Please find the fiddle link

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/jwy65yp3/5/`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding ID's to your HTML, and removing the #'s from your classes:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div id="cm-1" class="containerMenu">1</div>
    <div id="cm-2" class="containerMenu">2</div>
    <div id="cm-3" class="containerMenu">3</div>
    <div class="nav">
        <div id="ni-1" class="nav-item">ITEM 1</div>
        <div id="ni-2" class="nav-item">ITEM 2</div>
        <div id="ni-3" class="nav-item">ITEM 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.containerMenu, .nav-item').on({
        mouseenter: function(e) {
            var id = e.target.id.split('-')[1];
            $('#cm-' + id).show();
        },
        mouseleave: function(e) {
            var id = e.target.id.split('-')[1];
            $('#cm-' + id).hide();
        }
    });
});
```